# Getting started on parameterised surface

Tags: three.js

I got three.js working, but how can I best get started making a complex (multicurved) surface, that is parameterisable?

Say for instance somehow expressing (3D model data, or computational functions) a surface like the seat and back of a chair, where certain parameters like with, curvature, etc. can be manipulated in a GUI (recalculating and showing the updated model)?

Like which Geometry would be best for this kind of work? Any pointers to tutorials on this or very similar topics?

Comment: Maybe you want a [scripted geometry plugin](http://docs.autodesk.com/3DSMAX/15/ENU/MAXScript-Help/index.html?url=files/GUID-EC33589D-822A-4E79-9682-185EC5DBAB9F.htm,topicNumber=d30e104121)?

Comment: You could look into [geometry skinning](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=skinning#webgl_animation_skinning_additive_blending), but maybe you'd like to [ask in the Three.js forum](https://discourse.threejs.org/)? Usually questions on StackOverflow don't get answers when [requesting tutorials or other off-site resources](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).